# Frequency/count variable in r studio

Tags: r, frequency, weighted

Long-time lurker, typically use SPSS/graphpad for stats, sloowly but surely grinding away at learning how to use R studio.

In SPSS I have a dataset with three variables: insurance (categorical, 4 levels); npo_violation (categorical, 2 levels) and frequency (scale, this represents the frequency with which for example, medicaid did/did not violate npo).[example dataset in SPSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3myk.jpg)

I am trying to trying to bring this dataset with the frequency count variable into r-studio so that I can make grouped barcharts based on the percentages of combinations.

I have used foreign/haven/Hmisc to bring it into r studio and also created it myself

```
df_sample <- data.frame(insurance = c("Medicaid", "Medicaid", "Blue Cross", "Blue Cross",
                                      "Managed Care", "Managed Care",
                                      "Other", "Other"), 
                        npo_violation=c("No", "Yes",
                                        "No", "Yes",
                                        "No", "Yes",
                                        "No", "Yes"),
                        wt=c(18075, 438, 14691, 109, 6006, 53, 3098, 25))
```

I am not sure how to make it such that the count/frequency variable could be used to calculate the percentage/count of each categorical combination. So for example, calculate (and then graph) the percentage of "medicaid+no npo violation" and "medicaid+yes npo violation"
I have tried using the wtd.table function

```
wtd.table(df_sample$insurance, df_sample$npo_violation, weights=wt)
```

but I know that is not correct, and I receive error "Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector".

I am very intimidated to post on here but would GREATLY appreciate any help. Using R takes me forever but is very gratifying. Thanks.

EDIT: Ultimately, I would like to plot 
x axis: two variables, "no" and "yes".   legend would have 4 categories: medicaid, blue cross, managed care, other. y axis would be the percentages each insurance group accounted for within "yes" and "no" as seen in the crosstab i made in spss
[image]

Comment: Hi Rhino, can you edit your question to explain `I am not sure how to make it such that the count/frequency variable is reflected to be what I want it`? It sounds like a straightforward programming problem, but not sure I understand the desired outcome. Maybe you can insert the expected output of the code you are looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to `sum` the `wt` column for `insurance` and `npo_violation`? Try `aggregate(wt~insurance+npo_violation, df_sample, sum)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two plots based on your data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

df_sample %>% 
   mutate(percent=wt/sum(wt)) %>%    # calculates percent
   ggplot() +                        # launches plotter 
   geom_bar(aes(x=insurance, y=percent, fill=npo_violation), 
        stat="identity",position=position_dodge())  # bars
```

which generates this:

[image]

In the above example, you can swap the variables in `x` and `fill` to get the opposite grouping. You can also do:

```
df_sample %>% 
   mutate(tag=paste(insurance, npo_violation)) %>%     # combines labels
   mutate(percent=wt/sum(wt)) %>%                      # calculates percent
   ggplot(aes(x=tag,y=percent)) +                      # launches plotter
   geom_bar(stat="identity") +                         # tells it to take wt literally
   theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))  # x axis labels
```

[image]

Comment: holy f*** that was fast. and amazing. I think that I am actually trying to do, is plot in a barplot fashion

"yes" and "no" on the x-axis, with the relative proportions/percentages that each "insurance" made to "yes" and "no".

I am editing my initial post to include a cross-tabulation with the percentages I would LOVE to be able to plot.

Comment: if it works the way you like, please give it a check mark, otherwise let me know if there are still other ways remaining that you need to explore to finalize this question

Comment: I changed it ever so slightly

df_sample %>% 
  mutate(percent=wt/sum(wt)) %>%    # calculates percent
  ggplot() +                        # launches plotter 
  geom_bar(aes(x=npo_violation, y=percent, fill=insurance), 
           stat="identity",position=position_dodge())  # bars

THANK YOU!! Really took my nervousness away from posting here :)

Comment: I think the only gap is in printing a crosstab like you displayed above... that part is straightforward if you have all the observations individually because `CrossTable` in the`gmodels` package can count them up and display an `SPSS` formatted table. With the percentages already calculated, it's not as direct. Thanks and good luck learning!